# Could not resolve

Tags: android

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.

Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0.
Required by:
    project :app

Comment: Please show your project gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to your root level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
  }
 }
}

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **File -> Project Settings -> Gradle** and uncheck the Gradle offline work option.
2. Synchronize the project again and let all the Google maps dependencies get downloaded.